# Get the encrypted value in django-fernet-fields

Tags: python, django

I use the django-fernet-fields library:

```
class RoutePoint(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    password = EncryptedCharField(max_length=30, null=True)
```

When I access an encrypted field, the value of the field is automatically decrypted.

```
p = RoutePoint.objects.all()[0]
print(p.password)
> mypass
```

Is there any way I can get the encrypted value that is actually stored in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method that performs the decryption within the `model.Field` is `def from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection, *args)`. In theory, you could override this method for `RoutePoint.password` and have it return a tuple, with the first element being the raw field value and the second being the decrypted plaintext.

Here is a pointer to the relevant source code https://github.com/orcasgit/django-fernet-fields/blob/master/fernet_fields/fields.py#L74.

**Note:** `django-fernet-fields` hasn't been updated in over 3 years, and as a previous user myself, I forked the codebase to one that is backed by Google Tink instead https://github.com/script3r/django-tink-fields